# python regex match all character including newline

Tags: python, regex

In python I can't match all character including newline.
This is the string

```
<ebl:NotificationSignature xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  4tzL1OLLe3eEchFIDFFJbA==</ebl:NotificationSignature>
```

This is the regex I've used

```
re.findall('<ebl:NotificationSignature xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents>"(.*?)</ebl:NotificationSignature>', body)
```

I tried with this one:

```
    re.findall('<ebl:NotificationSignature xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents>"(.*?|\n*)</ebl:NotificationSignature>', body)
```

They return nothing. I am using python 2.7.

Comment: The first regex is fine, just use `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` as `flags` argument. However, an XML parser based solution would be more appropriate since you have XML.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the real issue is that the regex has `eBLBaseComponents>"` instead of `eBLBaseComponents">` (note that the positions of the `"` and `>` characters are swapped from their positions in the original string)

Comment: @Donut That is a typo, the real issue is stated at the top: *In python I can't match all character including newline.*

Comment: I had problem with namespace using xpath from lxml.  I only need few tags.